# How to add Facebook connect to an asp.net website (for novice)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

I was wondering if anyone can point me to a **tutorial / step by step guide / downloadable template (free or paid) / video** about adding Facebook connect functionality to a website.

I've created several website but I'm self learned and inexperienced. 
I have no knowledge of oAuth protocols simply basic asp.net (VB) of going to the database, getting data and posting it on the site.

I've gone through several posts on the matter but it seems that they changed lots of stuff from before 2012 (so most articles are irrelevant). I also went through Stackoverflow but the questions and answers are above my expertise.

My site is basic and was also built from scratch without using any existing methodology (like MVC etc.). I also tried working on a new site with the ready template Visual Studio 2012 sets up. The built in sign up form seems to work (though I do not understand what it does) and I removed some of the functionality which I think was created to enable Facebook connect since it bounced lots of errors I couldn't understood.

The end goal is to allow easy one step signup and signin while getting the user's email and maybe birth-date.

THANKS!

Comment: The VS2012 template is as easy as it's going to get. I suggest you work your way through the errors, hence gaining an understanding of what is going on. It's better to understand than just to use code you have no idea about.

Comment: @Alexander - Are you referring to the standard default template the site starts with? (with ready made sign in and sign up)

Comment: I'm getting the following exception: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. And the following line is marked:  If OpenAuth.Login(authResult.Provider, authResult.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie:=False) Then